# How to set vector icon asset's tint in jetpack compose?

Tags: vector, android-jetpack-compose

I used jetpack compose, imported a vector icon from `Resource Manager` (View->Tool Windows->Resource Manager) and got the following XML code.

But I got an error of `?attr/colorControlNormal` saying "not found".

Could some one tell me how to fix please? Thanks.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
  <path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change ?attr/colorControlNormal to ?android:colorControlNormal

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:tint="?android:colorControlNormal">
  <path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: This worked absolutely fine, thanks lots. I am now wondering why in some Jetpack Compose projects where I used `?attr/colorControlNormal` did not cause any issues with the Drawables.